# How to filter tables using Connection.getMetaData().getTables

Tags: jdbc, database-metadata

I have a huge schema that contains my application table, I need to return these tables only.

I've used the following:

```
ResultSet publicTables = jdbcConnection.getMetaData().getTables(null, schema, "USER_%", dataTypes);
```

The problem is, I've 6 tables started by the `USER_` keyword and two other arbitrary table names, how can I add `OR` filter for these two tables?

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. You will need to call getTables() several times (one call for each search expression)